# Kendo Grid get selected row from all pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to fetch a selected data from all the pages.

For example I select 1 item from the page 1 and the 2nd item from the page 2. When I click on the button (Get Checked Rows). I want to fetch those id's that I just selected from the different pages.

So far this is what I found, but it works for a single pages only. [FULL DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/uvOqASap)

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedRows = grid.select();
selectedRows.each(function(index, row) {
  var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(row);
  alert(selectedItem.ProductID);
});
```

*Is there any other way, instead creating a template/id for a checkbox.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the selectedKeyNames method rather than the select method.

If you update your code like this ([updated DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/uvOqASap/3)), you can see it work:

```
  $("#button").kendoButton({
    click: function(e){

      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      var selectedRows = grid.select();

      //show all selected keys across all pages
      alert(grid.selectedKeyNames());
      
      selectedRows.each(function(index, row) {
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(row);
        alert(selectedItem.ProductID + ' | ' + selectedItem.ProductName);
      });

    }  
  });
```

More info and a Telerik example can be found here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/checkbox-selection-dataitems-selected-rows